# Is some thing wrong with this sentence about 'Data_length' of InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

According to the MySQL manual：[SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-table-status.html)

> For InnoDB, **Data_length** is the approximate **amount of memory**
>   allocated for the clustered index, in bytes. Specifically, it is the
>   clustered index size, in pages, multiplied by the InnoDB page size.

I'm confused about **"amount of memory"** , since clustered index is stored on disk  , not in the memory.

I think the right expression should be as follows:

> For InnoDB, **Data_length** is the approximate **amount of disk space**
>   allocated for the clustered index, in bytes.

Who can help me to explain "**amount of memory**"?

Comment: Indexes get copied into memory when queries are being processed, so the disk space and the memory use are isomorphic.

Comment: @Barmar - No.  _Blocks_ are copied into memory, and _cached_ there.  You can have an index bigger than will fit in memory.

Comment: Should probably be "amount of storage".

Answer (score 2):

Yikes!  That is a cryptic sentence.  File a "documentation" bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .  "amount of memory" is a bad choice of words.

Here's some more info; hopefully I can explain it better.

An InnoDB table is mostly composed "data" and "indexes" (and some meta info and free space).  The data info *and* the `PRIMARY KEY` are both in a BTree, and the current size of that tree given, exactly, in `Data_length`.  It is an exact multiple of the block size, which defaults to 16KB.  So, the tiniest InnoDB table you can make will still say `Data_length=16384`.

The `PRIMARY KEY` is (always in InnoDB) "clustered" with the data.  The data is ordered by the PK.

Other indexes are called "secondary indexes; they live in separate BTree(s), the total length of which is `Index_length`.

The "buffer pool", of size `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, is a section of RAM where data and index *blocks* are cached for efficient use by the InnoDB Engine.  Until the table is opened, none of its blocks are in RAM.  The engine never deliberately loads the entire table (or an entire secondary index, etc) into RAM.

A related confusion...  `Rows` and `Avg_row_length` are approximate.  One is estimated, then the other is computed from `Data_length` divided by it.